# Assigning a key-pair value to a regular array vs assigning to a session array

Tags: php

I want to assign a key-value pair to an array, and my implementation looks something like this:

```
$ingredients = [];

$key1 = 100;
$value1 = 200;

$key2 = 300;
$value2 = 400;

$ingredients[$key1] = $value1;
$ingredients[$key2] = $value2;
```

However, the output is not what I expected. It looks like this:

```
array(
0 => 200,
1 => 400
);
```

I also tried doing it like this:

```
$ingredients[][$key1] = $value1;
$ingredients[][$key2] = $value2
```

But only resulted to a different output:

```
array(
0 => array(100 => 200),
1 => array(300 => 400)
);
```

But, when I try using a session, the output is correct.

```
$_SESSION['sessionname'][$key1] = $value1;
$_SESSION['sessionname'][$key2] = $value2;

array(
100 => 200,
300 => 400
);
```

What is the difference between how `$ingredients[]` and `$_SESSION['sessionname'][]` behave? And how do I implement the correct behavior using `$ingredients[]`?

Comment: Is there anything else happening in your code? [The first code block works as expected](https://3v4l.org/qS076).

Comment: I think you need to use strings for your effect to take place

Comment: You would get the first result if you wrote `$ingredients[] = $value1; $ingredients[] = $value2;`, not the code you posted.

Comment: @kero - I tried echoing `$key1` and `$value1` and they showed the correct values. But when assigned to `$ingredients` array like `$ingredients[$key1] = $value1`, the value of `$key1` is not reflected but get replaced with something like in my example above.

Comment: @fonsy Then something else might be interfering, without seeing more code it is impossible to help. As shown by my link, the initial code block works as intended.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Somewhere in my code I did `sort($ingredients)`. I noticed it changes all keys to a series of 1,2,3,... I tried removing that and the expected value is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in my code I did `sort($ingredients)`. I noticed it changes all keys to a series of 1,2,3,... I tried removing that and the expected value is displayed.

Comment: If you check [the docu on sorting methods](https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php), some "maintain key association". Use one of these functions instead of `sort()`.